# Floor plans: How to add wifi AP for indoor navigation

Tags: google-maps, navigation

I would like to use google maps for navigation in my building (warehouse).
How can I add a wifi access point for more accurate navigation?

I want to help refine google maps navigation via WIFI.

I am using
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/floorplans/

Thanks for the reply

Michal

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the Google Indoor Maps Team using the "request help" link on the floor plan help page (links to https://maps.google.com/floorplans/uploadcontactme).

They may choose to provide you with a mobile app that they use to walk buildings, verify floor plans, and collect wifi positions.

However, if your warehouse is not public, they will likely deny you, since your data is of limited benefit to the general public (look at their terms and conditions). But it's worth trying! So far, the team has been very helpful to me (I represent a university).